# Random color codes turning to #000000 on second try

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button that generates two random codes for two colors. It seems that is working on first click but on the second one both codes become like this **#000000**.

I tried to solve the problem on my own but I couldn't find a solution.
How could i solve the problem? Any advice would be appreciated.

```js
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById('gradient')
var random1 = document.getElementById("random1");
var random2 = document.getElementById("random2");
var colorGenerator = "1234567890ABCDEF";
var colortag1 = "#";
var colortag2 = "#";


 
function backgroundcolor(){
  body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right,"
 + color1.value + ","+ color2.value +")";

css.textContent = body.style.background;
}

css.textContent = "linear-gradient (to right, "
 + color1.value + ", "+ color2.value +")";

function randomColor (){
 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  colortag1 += colorGenerator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  colortag2 += colorGenerator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  color1.value = colortag1;
  color2.value = colortag2;
 }

  body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right,"
 + color1.value + ","+ color2.value +")";
   console.log(color1);
   console.log(color2);

  css.textContent = "linear-gradient (to right, "
 + color1.value + ", "+ color2.value +")";
  
 
} 



color1.addEventListener("input", backgroundcolor);
color2.addEventListener("input",backgroundcolor);
random1.addEventListener("click", randomColor);
```

```css
body {
 font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    top: 15%;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); /* Standard syntax */
}

h1 {
    font: 600 3.5em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    width: 100%;
}

h3 {
 font: 900 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;

}

button {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5) ;
    font: 800 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Gradient background</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">
 <h1>Backround Generator</h1>
 <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#FF0000">
 <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#FFFF00">
 <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
 <button id="random1">Random Colors</button>
 
 <h3></h3>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just log the values of `colortag1` and `colortag2` (or in other words: don't use global variables)

Comment: Try this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/random-hex-color/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On snippet code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        colortag1 += colorGenerator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        colortag2 += colorGenerator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        color1.value = colortag1;
        color2.value = colortag2;
    }
```

You are appending the color tag (colortag1 +=) so the second time the value is like '#7C247EEC3C75'.
You must assign the variable to empty string.

```
colortag1 = "#";
colortag2 = "#";
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        colortag1 += colorGenerator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        colortag2 += colorGenerator[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        color1.value = colortag1;
        color2.value = colortag2;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `colortag1` or `colortag2`, as Santiago Casas Rey noted. This would be easier to notice with more organized code. Things can get especially messy when messing around with Math.random(). I use [rando.js](https://randojs.com) to make my randomness simpler and more readable. You can get a random hex string with rando.js like this:

```js
function randomHex(){
  var hex = "#";
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) hex += ("0" + rando(255).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  return hex;
}

console.log(randomHex());
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

It can even be a one-liner if you want it to be:

```js
console.log( "#" + ("0" + rando(255).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + rando(255).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + rando(255).toString(16)).slice(-2) );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If we apply that to your js, it becomes:

```js
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById('gradient')
var random1 = document.getElementById("random1");

function randomHex() {
  var hex = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) hex += ("0" + rando(255).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  return hex;
}

function changeToColors(hex1, hex2){
  body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + hex1 + "," + hex2 + ")";
  css.textContent = body.style.background;
}

function changeToInputColors() {
  changeToColors(color1.value, color2.value);
}

function changeToRandomColors() {
  changeToColors(randomHex(), randomHex());
}

changeToInputColors();

color1.addEventListener("input", changeToInputColors);
color2.addEventListener("input", changeToInputColors);
random1.addEventListener("click", changeToRandomColors);
```

```css
body {
  font: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  top: 15%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

h1 {
  font: 600 3.5em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  font: 900 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

button {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  font: 800 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gradient background</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="gradient">
    <h1>Backround Generator</h1>
    <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#FF0000">
    <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#FFFF00">
    <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
    <button id="random1">Random Colors</button>
    <h3></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

If want to use this code, just don't forget to include this line in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```